# PeopleSoft Query Manager Table Name

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

I cannot for the life of me figure out the table name that would enable me to see the approval queue.

There is time pending approval in the approval process "TLReportedTime" and I'm looking for a table to build a report so that I can see **who** the approval is pending with...

Comment: Using the navigation in the PIA, can you see it via a screen? If so, determine menu/component/page and open the page in PeopleTools Application Designer to determine the underlying Record Field that stores this data.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have access to Application Designer.

Comment: Enable the sql trace. Access the queue. Ask some admin to get you the trace file. Table will be there

Comment: If you can get PS Query access to the PSPNLFIELD table,  you can query the page for a list of fields (including their label text).

Comment: as I recall, you can use your browser to inspect table and fieldnames - most fields have CSS classnames that map to at least fieldname if not table name as well.  now, sometimes the field being displayed is a work table so, not the actual physical table so that wouldn't help in those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(PS_)EOAW_USERINST is the table that stores the information with who a step's approval is pending with.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment, in the more generic case, rather than @Robin's correct answer, you want to check the HTML `input name` via Inspect Element in Browser.

Taking a screen I am currently looking at and using right-click `Inspect` in browser, you get my screenshot.

The field and table names are concatenated and separated with a `_` which is perhaps not the best choice as underscores are widely used in names.

`TL_RUN_CTRL_GRP` and `EMPLID` are table and field names, respectively.

[image]

Take note:  depending on specific PeopleSoft page, table names can sometimes be those of in-memory-only work tables, which is going to be of limited use for writing queries.